# How to implement TvView on Android TV?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-tv, television

### Goal

To create a reduced *TvView* that displays on top of a *WebView*.
**This is specifically for live TV.**
(I've seen numerous solutions that address *streaming* content, but this is intended for video that's delivered through the coaxial cable.)

[image: Layout]

### Where I'm At Now

The *WebView* portion works fine, and I've learned that a *RelativeLayout* is required in order to layer views.
Also, *TvView* doesn't seem to be recognized, so I'm guessing that I'll probably need to use a *SurfaceView* instead.

**activity_main.xml**
[image: Code example]

**MainActivity.java**
[image]

### Questions

I've seen the *TvInput*, example applications, but it's extremely excessive.  I'm not trying to recreate the *TvInput* service, just leverage on existing framework.

- Is it possible to simply call on the existing, TV service that's already on the Android device, and display it in a view?
- If it *is* possible, how is it accomplished?
- If it's *not* possible, what's the simplest method of implementing it? (repository links would be great.)

I've searched all over for answers but can't seem to find anything.
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

---

### Code in Text Format

As requested by *tung*.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="com.company.app.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.company.app.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TvView
        android:id="@+id/TvView"
        android:layout_width="816dp"
        android:layout_height="404dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout >
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.company.app;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.media.tv.TvView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private TvView mTvView;
    private WebSettings mWebSettings;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.28.98.150:1000/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        this.setContentView(mWebView);
        mTvView = new TvView(this );
        mTvView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        this.setContentView(mTvView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: pls add code as text and not as screenshot

Comment: There you go.  Added code in text format.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String channelUrl="content://android.media.tv/channel/"+channelNumber;
        mTvView.tune(mInputId, Uri.parse(channelUrl));
```

input id is available in TV database(refering to which source channel is coming from).

If you pass these info to tvview it will start playing.